# Matlab: one-dim integral for a function @(x,y,z)

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, numerical-integration, dimension-reduction

Lets say

> ```
>  y=2;
>  z=4;
>  f=@(x,y,z) x.^2+y.^2+z.^2;
> ```

And I want to integrate f for x in [0,1].
It seems like I have to define g and do quad(g,0,1)

> ```
>  g=@(x) f(x,y,z); 
>  quad(g,0,1)
> ```

The question I have is whether it is possible to do quad on f directly without defining a new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ; you can use the [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) directly as an argument.

```
quad(@(x)f(x,y,z),0,1);
```